# PHP Submit Form is Ignoring Values that Start w/ Zero

Tags: javascript, php, forms, parsing

I am running into this problem. where I want to pass a value I have scraped earlier. Specifically, the values are movie codes from IMDB.

I have parsed in a foreach statement the imdb number like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(RSS URL Here);
$items = $xml->xpath('//item');

foreach ( $items as $item) {
    $myimdb = $item->imdb;   

    echo $myimdb;    //this echoes fine

    <form action='JavaScript:getTrailers({$myimdb})' method='POST' id='{$myimdb}'>
    <input type='hidden' id='movieid'  name='movieid' value='{$myimdb}'>
    <a  href='javascript:;' onclick='parentNode.submit();'>Get Trailer</a>

}
```

My JS script for getTrailers looks like:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getTrailers(movieid)
{
   $("#mytrailers").load("trailersearch.php",$("#test" + movieid).serialize());  
}
</SCRIPT>
```

In my trailersearch.php I have code that look like this:

```
$theimdb = $_GET["movieid"];
echo "{$theimdb}<br>";
```

If a movie has an imdb ID that does not start with zero, like 1234567, the code executes properly and trailersearch.php echoes the number correctly.

But if an ID starts with zero, like 0123456, the $theimdb variable is blank and echoes blank. Many of theolder IMDB movies start with0 or even 00.

Can anyone please help me resolve this. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. I am not a super expert.

Many thanks,

Hernando

Comment: Probably not related, but you should start with generating valid html: You have duplicate ID's and your forms are not closed. I also don't see any elements that have an ID starting with `test`. And you should post the html source code instead of the php to see whether the problem is in the javascript or in the php.

Comment: What is sent to javascript function getTrailers(movieid) when movieid starts with 0?
 Can you verify by alerting on console logging the value of movieid.

Comment: Thank you guys... The code is a an extremely simplified version of what I am actually doing. I may have made typos when doing my code here. But the gist is that it works with non-zero starting numbers. @Nawed- I hate to say that I dont know how to check what you suggest. I peck away in Notepad++ and refresh my browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='JavaScript:getTrailers({$myimdb})'
```

That is the problem – you *neglected* to put quotes around the parameter value here, so that for JavaScript it *is* a number – and numbers don’t *have* “leading zeroes”.

So make that

```
<form action='JavaScript:getTrailers("{$myimdb}")'
```

and it should work fine.

(And you are lucky you did not run into even more serious problems, because given the right digits, JS could have interpreted the value as an *octal* number – and then you would not only have lost the leading zero, but gotten a completely different value altogether …)

Comment: Thank you... I have been racking my brain for 6 hours on this. The problem is that my form is buried in code inside php. The only way I can get the form to pass anything, is without the quotes as I show. No type of quote combination work... I have tried ' " \" and none work. Some prevent anything from loading, others, the form just does not submit.

Comment: Well then you _will have to_ figure out a way to get the quotes in there – otherwise it won’t work.